# \defaultfontfeatures in v2.4 of fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Why in the following example, lipsum text does not appear in blue color as described in the fontspec manual?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Times New Roman}
\defaultfontfeatures[\myfont]{Color=blue}
\begin{document}
\myfont
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `fontspec` user guide states that `\defaultfontfeatures` is used to "define font features that are applied to every *subsequent* font selection command" (emphasis added). Conversely, the macro does *not* operate on fonts that were set up earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is somehow strange but it seems that `\defaultfontfeatures` needs to be before `\newfontfamily`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[\myfont]{Scale=2}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\myfont
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see that it's strange: once a family is declared it's fixed, just like any other definition.